# Defining a collation option with a JPA CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, criteria-api

I have been looking around internet for adding a collation to a column by using a CriteriaBuilder (or any other JPA mechanism) but there seems no way to do this. Is this feature not supported in the JPA API? For sure I could try a SQL statement such as:

```
SELECT  * FROM person p 
WHERE p.lastname like 'Müller' COLLATE LATIN_AI;
```

And this would work fine in my Oracle DB but I would like to keep my existing query that uses JPA criteria/query builder and not change into the above statement.

Comment: could you change the collation of the database?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I cannot change the collation of the database or the tables. Apparently this feature is not supported within the CriteriBuilder or even the HQL. In the end I had to create a native SQL with 
    getEntityManager().createNativeQuery(queryStr, Person.class)

Comment: Collation in your query make sense only if your table(s) are created with this explicit intention. Otherwise, this is not supported, even if specified in your Criteria/HQL/JPQL query

Comment: Supposing you say it explicitely in your creation SQL script, you can specify to use collation with JPA criteria. Ex. with MySQL DB :
private Predicate predicateOfString(String criteria, Path<String> fieldPath) {
        return getCriteriaBuilder().like(
                getCriteriaBuilder().function("collate_ai_ci", String.class, fieldPath),
                "%" + criteria + "%"
        );
    }